# list comprehension in python with if and else

Tags: python

after i test,

```
len_stat = [len(x) if len(x) > len_stat[i] else len_stat[i] for i, x in enumerate(a_list)]
```

is same with

```
for i, x in enumerate(a_list):
    if len(x) > len_stat[i]:
        len_stat[i] = len(x)
```

of course, but,

```
len_stat = [len(x) if len(x) > len_stat[a_list.index(x)] else len_stat[a_list.index(x)] for x in a_list]
```

is different with

```
for x in a_list:
    if len(x) > len_stat[a_list.index(x)]:
        len_stat[a_list.index(x)] = len(x)
```

later, i know `<list>.index` is a bad method used here.

but why they are different in last two examples?

---

my fault! here is my test code,

```
a_list = ['Bacteroides fragilis YCH46', 'YCH46', '20571', '-', 'PRJNA13067', 'FCB group', 'Bacteroidetes/Chlorobi group', 'GCA_000009925.1 ', '5.31099', '43.2378', 'chromosome:NC_006347.1/AP006841.1; plasmid pBFY46:NC_006297.1/AP006842.1', '-', '2', '4717', '4625', '2004/09/17', '2016/08/03', 'Complete Genome', 'ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF_000009925.1_ASM992v1', 'ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA_000009925.1_ASM992v1']

len_stat_1 = [0 for x in a_list]
len_stat_2 = [0 for x in a_list]
len_stat_3 = [0 for x in a_list]
len_stat_4 = [0 for x in a_list]

len_stat_1 = [len(x) if len(x) > len_stat_1[i] else len_stat_1[i] for i, x in enumerate(a_list)]

for i, x in enumerate(a_list):
    if len(x) > len_stat_2[i]:
        len_stat_2[i] = len(x)

len_stat_3 = [len(x) if len(x) > len_stat_3[a_list.index(x)] else len_stat_3[a_list.index(x)] for x in a_list]

for x in a_list:
    if len(x) > len_stat_4[a_list.index(x)]:
        len_stat_4[a_list.index(x)] = len(x)

print len_stat_1
print len_stat_2
print len_stat_3
print len_stat_4
```

output:

```
[26, 5, 5, 1, 10, 9, 28, 16, 7, 7, 72, 1, 1, 4, 4, 10, 10, 15, 63, 63]
[26, 5, 5, 1, 10, 9, 28, 16, 7, 7, 72, 1, 1, 4, 4, 10, 10, 15, 63, 63]
[26, 5, 5, 1, 10, 9, 28, 16, 7, 7, 72, 1, 1, 4, 4, 10, 10, 15, 63, 63]
[26, 5, 5, 1, 10, 9, 28, 16, 7, 7, 72, 0, 1, 4, 4, 10, 10, 15, 63, 63]
```

as you can see, the last two is different!

it really confused me.

Comment: What is different? What input do you use, what output do you get, and what output do you expect?

Comment: how does your `a_list` look like? Can you add the input that you tested with?

Comment: Thank you guys help me! Sorry, i add my test code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This list comprehension:

```
len_stat = [len(x) if len(x) > len_stat[a_list.index(x)] else len_stat[a_list.index(x)] for x in a_list]
```

Is equivalent to:

```
temp = []
for x in a_list:
    temp.append(len(x) if len(x) > len_stat[a_list.index(x)] else len_stat[a_list.index(x)])
len_stat = temp
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
temp = []
for x in a_list:
    if len(x) > len_stat[a_list.index(x)]:
        val = len(x)
    else:
        val = len_stat[a_list.index(x)]
    temp.append(val)
len_stat = temp
```

Equivalent, of course, except for the `temp` list. The comprehension approach will replace `len_stat` with a new list, that will always be the same length as `len_stat` that will have either `len(x)` for every x in `len_stat` or will have `len_stat[a_list.index(x)]`. The for-loop you wrote will mutate `len_stat` based on the conditional, and it's hard to say exactly what will happen without knowing the content of your lists, but it could potentially change values of `len_stat` all over the place.

### To be clear

I do **not** recommend this approach, but I am trying to illustrate how the comprehension is different than the for-loop.

Comment: I think it's better if you do, `len_stat = temp[:]`

Comment: @kmario23 I think it's better if you don't use this approach *at all*.

Comment: Yes! you are right! I **mutate** the list when i for-loop it, it case unexpected results. And sorry for not accepting for a long time.